# Looking to export a list of coordinates to a gpx file

Tags: java, android

I have an android program that I need to build that exports some gps coordinates to a gpx file. This is my code so far. Im looking to find out the best way of storing the gps coordinates from the location manager to then pass to the gpx file.

**Main Activity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    LocationListener locationListener;
    LocationManager locationManager;

    public void StartRec(View view, int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, (LocationListener) this);
            }

        }

        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

            }
        };

    }

    public void stopRec(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Statistics.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list of [Location](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location) class as below :

```
public static void generateGfx(File file, String name, List<Location> points) {

String header = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\" ?><gpx xmlns=\"http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1\" creator=\"MapSource 6.15.5\" version=\"1.1\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"  xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd\"><trk>\n";
name = "<name>" + name + "</name><trkseg>\n";

String segments = "";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
for (Location location : points) {
    segments += "<trkpt lat=\"" + location.getLatitude() + "\" lon=\"" + location.getLongitude() + "\"><time>" + df.format(new Date(location.getTime())) + "</time></trkpt>\n";
}

String footer = "</trkseg></trk></gpx>";

try {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, false);
    writer.append(header);
    writer.append(name);
    writer.append(segments);
    writer.append(footer);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("generateGfx", "Error Writting Path",e);
}}
```

[You can refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46491045/8159810)

Comment: @Abdullah Khan, feel free to remove your own comments. But dont remove comments where i compliment Rozina for a to the point answer.